# Could anyone help me on how to encrypt a file using Kleopatra in PowerShell scripting?

Tags: powershell, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt a .txt file to .txt.gpg file using Kleopatra in powershell. But getting error in powershell. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the snippet that I've tried:

```
$kleopatraPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\bin\kleopatra.exe"
$inputFile = "D:\Work\data.txt"
$expectedOutputFile = "D:\Work\data.txt.gpg"
$encryptionKeyPath = "D:\Work\key.asc"

Invoke-Item $kleopatraPath {-i --import-certificate $encryptionKeyPath -e -- encrypt $inputFile }
```

Expected result: output file "D:\Work\data.txt.gpg".

Error I'm getting:

```
Invoke-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-i
--import-certificate "D:\Work\QA Batches\CCI\CCI-10050 FW Conversant UC4 Job
request\encryption key\narnia.epsilon.com.asc" -e -- encrypt "D:\Work\QA
Batches\CCI\CCI-10050 FW Conversant UC4 Job request\test\
etInvAdjust_invadjustcre_2223539_1_2019-04-10_10-49-02-856 - Copy2.xml"'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\bin\kleopatra.exe" {-i  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand
```

Comment: Use the call operator (`&`), not `Invoke-Item`, and remove the curly brackets.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers :
Thanks for you suggestion but unfortunately this new approach isn't working. I'm getting below error from Kleopatra.exe.

#Ambiguous commands &quot;encrypt&quot; and &quot;import-certificate&quot;

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

See the defined methods for running external tools like this from TechNet.

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

As per Ansgar's suggestion:

> 5. The Call Operator & Technet
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing
>   with spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another
>   command that starts with a number, you have to use the command
>   invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case you don’t
>   need the & anymore .
>
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator,
>   also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that
>   are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call
>   operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command
>   parameters

```
# Example: 

& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters
>   or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
>
> With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not
>   always clear!
>
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

# or same like that:

$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')

& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

Or Start-Process.

> 7. Start-Process  (start/saps) Technet
>
> Why: Starts a process and returns the .Net process object  if
>   -PassThru is provided. It also allows you to control the environment in which the process is started (user profile, output redirection
>   etc). You can also use the Verb parameter (right click on a file, that
>   list of actions) so that you can, for example, play a wav file.
>
> Details: Executes a program returning the process object of the
>   application. Allows you to control the action on a file (verb
>   mentioned above) and control the environment in which the app is run.
>   You also have the ability to wait on the process to end. You can also
>   subscribe to the processes Exited event.

```
# Example: 

# starts a process, waits for it to finish and then checks the exit code.
$p = Start-Process ping -ArgumentList "invalidhost" -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$p.HasExited
$p.ExitCode


# to find available Verbs use the following code.

$startExe = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -args PowerShell.exe
$startExe.verbs
```